# Find $f^{(12)}(1)$ for $f(x)={x+1 \over (x-3)(x^2-2x+5)}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I want to find $f^{(12)}(1)$ for
$$f(x)={x+1 \over (x-3)(x^2-2x+5)}$$
First, we substitute $x=1+t$ to get
$$f(t)={t+2 \over (t-2)(t^2+4)}$$
Let's assume $t \neq2$. Then
$$f(t)={t^2-4 \over t^2+4}={t^2+4-8 \over t^2+4}= 1 - {8 \over t^2+4}= 1 - 2{1 \over 1 + {t^2 \over 4}}$$
Using ${1 \over 1- x}=1+x+x^2+\dots$ we get
$$f(t)=1-2\left(1-{t^2 \over 2^2}+{t^4 \over 2^4}-{t^6 \over 2^6}+\dots \right)=1-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n{1\over 2^{2n}}t^{2n}$$
We can check that this in fact converges for $r=4$. Since we are looking for $f^{(12)}(0)$ (after substitution), our assumption of $t \neq 2$ is valid. Now, we use the fact that $a_n={f^{(n)}(x_0)\over n!}$.
$$f^{(12)}(0)= 12!(-1)^{12}{1\over 2^{2\times 12}}={12! \over 2^{24}}$$
While this doesn't look very bad at first, numerical inspection shows that we should get a negative number. I suspect my use of indexes might be off but can't quite pinpoint the problem.

**EDIT:**

Clearly, we cannot transform $f(t)$ the way I did. Do you have any other suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Why did you change $f(t)$ from $\frac{t+2}{(t-2)(t^2+4)}$ to $\frac{t^-4}{t^2+4}$? You just changed the whole function that way

Comment: @imranfat is correct. The correct function should be $$f(t)=\frac{t^2-4}{(t-2)^2(t^2+4)}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

$$f(t)=\frac{t+2}{(t-2)(t^2+4)}\ne\frac{t^2-4}{t^2+4}$$

Correctly, one should have

$$2f(t)=\frac1{t-2}+\frac t{t^2+4}$$

Now by geometric series we have

$$\frac1{t-2}=\frac{-1/2}{1-\frac t2}=-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac t2\right)^n$$

$$\frac t{t^2+4}=\frac{t/4}{1+\frac{t^2}4}=\frac t4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{t^2}8\right)^n$$

And you know what to do from here?

Comment: Thanks. One nitpick is the minus in the second equation.

Comment: Oops!  Good catch!.